# Laurent Series of $\frac{e^{z}}{(z+1)^{2}}, 0<|z+1|<\infty $

Tags: complex-analysis

$\frac{e^{z}}{(z+1)^{2}}, 0<|z+1|<\infty $

I am utterly unable to solve this problem.

I have tried to write it as $e^(z-2\ln(z+1))$, but the resulting series is completely hideous.

I have tried to find the Laurent series of $\frac{1}{(z+1)^2}$, but I do not seem to be able to decompose it as partial fraction.

Wolfral Alpha gave the answer of $\sum_{n=-2}^{\infty}\frac{(1+z)^n}{e(2+n)!}$

I could not arrive at the answer.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\frac{{{e^z}}}
{{{{\left( {z + 1} \right)}^2}}} = \frac{{{e^{\left( {z + 1} \right) - 1}}}}
{{{{\left( {z + 1} \right)}^2}}} = \frac{{{e^{ - 1}}.{e^{z + 1}}}}
{{{{\left( {z + 1} \right)}^2}}} = \frac{1}
{e}.\frac{1}
{{{{\left( {z + 1} \right)}^2}}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{{\left( {z + 1} \right)}^k}}}
{{k!}}}  = \frac{1}
{e}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{{\left( {z + 1} \right)}^{k - 2}}}}
{{k!}}} ,$$
for $0<|z+1|$.